# Structured form submission at Jenkins project pages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I want to get user input through some textboxes on the project page in Jenkins but struggle with retrieving the values back to the server side. I've tried [structured form submission](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Structured+Form+Submission) in various ways but with no positive result..

I've got it to work before but that was at the config page of a job (as mentioned in the link above) which is not what I am looking for now. The documentation does not mention much about this kind of feature except in config.jelly/global.jelly which is sad...

I have the textboxes up on the project page (the page that comes up when a job has been clicked) by adding them to my jobMain.jelly file but I don't know why form submission inside `<form>` tags don't work now..

What I'm asking is how I get user input from the project page back to my java code so that I can manipulate it there as I desire?

Thanks!

Comment: I have managed it in the past, but I don't have the code anymore. Make sure you extend the Builder class of Jenkins itself. Have you followed this tutorial?
 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Create+a+new+Plugin+with+a+custom+build+Step

Comment: I have seen it before but I don't think it's to any help. There they add additional configurations in the configuration page of a job and make use of structured form submissions via the config.jelly file, which as I stated above, is not what I'm looking for.

I want to use that kind of behaviour but on the project/job page, the  same page where the default disable/enable button is placed, but this kind of information nowhere to be found on the jenkins-wiki. Also which jelly file corresponds to what page, which makes jenkins plugin development "guess-develop" instead of "read-develop"...